# Using buttons to change color in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm trying to create a HTML button that when pressed, it changes the color of my simple triangle object in webgl. I have the button set up in a way that when pressed, a new vec4 set to green, blue, or red is assigned and then sends that data to the buffer again but I am doing something very wrong as the color does not change. any pointers? This is a homework assignment so I don't want full answers, just pointed in the next direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there are three approaches to this.

1. Update the vertexbuffer data and change the color attribute stored on the vertices, then set the new data by binding the buffer and using `bufferData` to update the buffer on the gpu side.
2. Use a uniform in your fragment shader and set the color using the uniform.
3. Have a one pixel texture and use this in your fragment shader, update the color in the texture and use `texImage2D` to update the texture on the gpu side.

I'm assuming you just forgot to call `bufferData` to sync your updated vertex buffer to the gpu.